# How to find sql query in weblogic

Tags: oracle, weblogic

I support an application whose UI is built on weblogic server. I need to know the sql query fired in the database whenever any action is performed on UI. Since there a lot of users hence I need to know is there any specific action through which I can identify it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your managed server logs should give you queries run through a PreparedStatement. Any database will give you auditing capabilities so you can track what SQL was run, origins and parameters passed.